# How to simulate a fixed size char array in python

Tags: python, arrays, emulation

I was inquiring myself the best way (or any good way actually) of simulating a small ram memory in Python.

In most languages, I would simply create a fixed size array of char, but this seems to be surprisingly complex in Python.

The closest thing I found was this:

```
self.two_KB_internal_ram = [] #goes from $0000-$07FF
    for x in range (2048):
        self.two_KB_internal_ram = 0
    print ("two_KB_internal_ram: ", type(self.two_KB_internal_ram))
```

However, the type shows that the type is an int, and not char.
Is there a way of doing this with chars? If not (or even if there is), what would be a good way to emulate a ram memory?

Comment: Well, there is a built-in `array` module that might be useful here.  If you wanted to use an ordinary list, you'd initialize it as `[0] * 2048`.  (Your attempt failed because you simply overwrote the list with an int, 2048 times.)

Comment: You do realize you have same name for list and int

Comment: @jasonharper. Is there a way to use it with chars ?

Comment: @mad_ "You do realize you have same name for list and int"  Not really. What I see is that I had an empty list called "two_KB_internal_ram". The only int I see is 0

Comment: Yes because you are overwriting the list with int by using the same name

Answer (score 0):

To get a fixed sized Array you can use `np.array` which ist capable of Holding Strings aswell

Something Like this:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(["a"] * 2048)
```

But why would you do that in Python?